# Inject Ember.Controller model into Ember.Service

Tags: ember.js

How can I access the "model" in an `Ember.Controller` from an `Ember.Service`? In my case I need the ember-data model in a url such as `http://localhost:4200/users/4/groups`. In a route I can simply do `this.modelFor('users')`

Comment: A service should normally be independent of the route/model structure. If you need it to deal with a model, is there some reason you can't pass it in?

Comment: Yeah, I can probably refactor to pass it in I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the "model" in an `Ember.Controller` from an `Ember.Service`.
You can only [inject controller](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_controller) in another controller. You need to pass model data to Service method and get your work done.